# Issue while importing secret value in aws-cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

In AWS-CDK,

In `stack-A`, I exported a secret value using below code

```
        core.CfnOutput(
            self,
            "db-secret",
            value=secret_arn,
            export_name= "db-secret",
        )
```

above code successfully exported `secret arn`

In `stack-B`, i want to import the `secret-arn` and want to extract the `secret value`

I am using below code to achieve the task

```
        secret = sm.Secret.from_secret_attributes(self, "ImportedSecret",
          secret_complete_arn=db_secret
        )
```

when i am try to use this `secret` as a environmental variable in the `fargate task_definition`, i am encountering below error.

```
    raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Expected a string, got {"$jsii.byref":"@aws-cdk/core.SecretValue@10330"}
```

**Can anyone tell me how to import the value of the secret**

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use it for the task definition? Note that the task definition can handle secrets directly such that the task definition does not contain the cleartext secret but just the reference and then ecs takes care of resolving that secret at container launch. Look at the `secrets` section of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-readme.html .

Comment: basically i have a spring boot application which is deployed as a `ECS-Fargate cluster`. the spring boot application need to connect to the `RDS-DB`. For this Reason, i want to provide RDS_DB password as a environmental variable.

Comment: Then take a look at the link and how you should send / use secrets in task definitions